# In which way is this question about Drupal development off-topic?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

I am referring to [Replacing drupal registration and login with facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405438/replacing-drupal-registration-and-login-with-facebook-login) that has been closed as off-topic. What is the rationale behind that?

- The question is about developing, as stated in the first lines
- The OP explains what he already tried
- The OP describes what he is not able to do

The question is probably a not good question, but from this to defining it off-topic there is quite a difference. The message given to the OP, when saying the question is off-topic, is that he should not ask questions about Drupal development on *Stack Overflow*, while the user can find many questions about that on the same site.

Comment: maybe because we have http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Development questions about Drupal are still on-topic on _Stack Overflow_.

Comment: i'm not against them, but I think some people could consider that they are off topic just because we have drupal.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally closed it as off-topic pending a request to be migrated over to the [Drupal StackExchange site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

As per the [Drupal StackExchange site FAQ section "What kind of questions can I ask here?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), this falls under the following point:

- Drupal development/theming how-tos

That said, your points about the question's legitimacy on SO *are* valid (it's on-topic on SO and on Drupal) so I've reopened it, but left it open to migration to the Drupal site.